# Implementing a custom login sequence

Tags: authentication, digital-experience, loginflow

I have generated a login discovery handler in my digital experience site and edited the auto-generated Apex:

```apex
    global class AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler1660570725472 implements Auth.LoginDiscoveryHandler {
    
        global PageReference login(String identifier, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
            if (identifier != null) {
                // Search for user by account number
                List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Account.Jade_Customer_Number__pc =:identifier AND IsActive = TRUE];
                if (!users.isEmpty() && users.size() == 1) {
                    List<TwoFactorMethodsInfo> verifiedInfo = [SELECT HasTotp FROM TwoFactorMethodsInfo WHERE UserId = :users[0].Id];
                    if (!verifiedInfo.isEmpty() && verifiedInfo[0].HasTotp == true) {
                        // Use SMS verification method if the user's account number is verified.
                        return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.TOTP, startUrl, requestAttributes);
                    } else {
                        // Use password verification method as fallback if the user's account number is unverified.
                        return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.PASSWORD, startUrl, requestAttributes);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No unique user found. User count=' + users.size());
                }
            }
            throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('Invalid Identifier');
        }
    
        private PageReference getSsoRedirect(User user, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
            // You can look up if the user should log in with SAML or an Auth Provider and return the URL to initialize SSO.
            return null;
        }
    
        private PageReference discoveryResult(User user, Auth.VerificationMethod method, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
            //Only external users with an External Identity or community license can login using Site.passwordlessLogin
            //Use getSsoRedirect to enable internal user login for a community
            PageReference ssoRedirect = getSsoRedirect(user, startUrl, requestAttributes);
            if (ssoRedirect != null) {
                return ssoRedirect;
            } else {
                if (method != null) {
                    List<Auth.VerificationMethod> methods = new List<Auth.VerificationMethod>();
                    methods.add(method);
                    PageReference pwdlessRedirect = Site.passwordlessLogin(user.Id, methods, startUrl);
                    if (pwdlessRedirect != null) {
                        return pwdlessRedirect;
                    } else {
                        throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No Passwordless Login redirect URL returned for verification method: ' + method);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No method found');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the setting in the community:

[image: Setup looks like this]

However the login page only contains 1 field.

[image: Login page]

Is it possible to add another field to this page? We are using 2FA so on the next screen the user is prompted to enter the verification code from the 2FA app. Is it possible to add another field to this page (in this example it will be a password field)?

Comment: Take a look at [Login Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow_examples.htm&type=5), there's a MFA example in the doc and many other examples are floating around.